# Need to show SelectCheckboxMenu as SelectManyMenu in Primefaces component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am developing an application with `Primefaces 5.1` and `JSF 2.2`.

In my project, I used `SelectManyMenu` to select multiple user's, in that we can't select all user's by single `checkbox` clicking (Select All option). So that I go to `SelectCheckboxMenu` component.

But in `SelectCheckboxMenu` component,it does not show as `SelectManyMenu` like not opened that menu panel default to select the user's directly instead of one more additional click on `SelectCheckboxMenu` to show SelectCheckboxMenu panel and then select the user's.

**Expecting:**

[image]

**Actual:**

[image]

Comment: Instead of this component why can't you try p:selectManyMenu in primefaces

Comment: @Arun Prasath, It possible but in p:selectManyMenu component does not have select all option.